# Avoiding deprecation warning on matchPattern against a Regex in ScalaTest

Tags: regex, scala, scalatest

Consider the following code intended to test `IdentifierRe` and `IntPart`:

```
// Code under test
val IdentifierRe = "([a-z]+)([0-9]+)".r
object IntPart {
  def unapply(arg: String): Option[Int] = Some(arg.toInt)
}

// Test cases
"foo123" should matchPattern { case IdentifierRe("foo", IntPart(123)) => }
"foo 123" should not fullyMatch IdentifierRe
```

It compiles but gives the following warning:

> warning: method unapplySeq in class Regex is deprecated (since 2.11.0): extracting a match result from anything but a CharSequence or Match is deprecated

I believe the problem is that `matchPattern` accepts `PartialFunction[Any, _]`, leading to deprecated `Regex#unapplySeq(Any)` getting used for extraction. I could work around it with:

```
"foo123" match {
  case IdentifierRe("foo", IntPart(123)) => succeed
  case _ => fail
}
```

Or even:

```
"foo123" should fullyMatch regex (IdentifierRe withGroups("foo", "123"))
```

But is there a more succinct way to avoid the warning while still using the `IntPart` extractor in the test case? The idea is that `IdentifierRe` and `IntPart` are often used together to pattern match and we'd want to mimic that in the test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider defining [custom matcher](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#usingCustomMatchers) like so

```
def matchRegexPattern(right: PartialFunction[String, _]): Matcher[String] =
  (left: String) =>
    MatchResult(
      right.isDefinedAt(left),
      s"$left does not match regex pattern",
      s"$left does match regex pattern "
    )
```

Note how we replaced `Any` with `String` in `PartialFunction[String, _]` which should take care of the warning. Now pattern match like so

```
"foo123" should matchRegexPattern { case IdentifierRe("foo", IntPart(123)) => }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case, though, the purpose of the test is to exercise `IdentifierRe` and `IntPart`. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't been able to come up with a better solution either. Accepting.